# Is there a way to disable the backup job critical warning in BHM?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, mbv, bhm

Is there a way to disable the backup job critical warning in BHM?

On non-production environments, our DBA's would prefer to use their custom backup's, rather than the standard BizTalk SQL Agent job.

Checked the section "Query Caption" for SQL Jobs, but can't see anything relating to the `Backup BizTalk Server (BizTalkMgmtDb)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, custom backup (w/o stopping the host instances) is not supported so using custom backup solution is not recommended

Second, there is no specific rule for this critical warning. This warning is generated by a more global rule that can be disabled but it will also disable then other important job warnings, so we don't recommend to disable it.